# How to add custom method in laravel eloquent class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

> I want to add some specific custom method to Laravel Eloquent so that
>   I can access those method from any Modal.

Like

```
class Bar extends Eloquent
{
    public $table = 'mytable';

    public function foo($log_table)
    {
        self::checkAndCreateLogTable($log_table); //<-- this 'll be a custom function defined in Eloquent
    }

}
```

I have one solution that is to create a base class and extend Eloquent and then extend the new class from all the modal like this

```
class Foo extends Eloquent
{

    public function checkAndCreateLogTable($log_table)
    {
        //get the table name from the modal and do some stuff
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo
{

}
```

Is there any better solution then this?

Comment: you can add abstract class (extend Model) as parent of all model or use trait

Comment: create basemodel and class YourModel extends BaseModel

Comment: @xmhafiz: ya trait is a good idea. just out of the curiosity is it possible to write some custom method in Eloquent in Laravel way, so that I don't hamper ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

If the method `checkAndCreateLogTable` will be used in literally every model you create (also in future), it would be easier to create a class that extends the `Eloquent` class.

If not you should create a `trait`. Eg:

```
trait HasLogTable
{
    public function checkAndCreateLogTable ($log_table)
    {
        // Get the table name from the model and do some stuff
    }
}

class Bar extend Eloquent
{
    use HasLogTable;
}
```

However if this is only a one time task at the beginning of you application installation I would create a console command (or migration seen the name of the method?).

Comment: Thanks @thomas for the answer, trait is a good idea. Just out of the curiosity is it possible to write some custom method in Eloquent in Laravel way, so that I don't hamper ecosystem. and I'll keep this question open for a day or two if didn't get any other way 'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Promit Well, traits are an excellent selective way to prevent intruding into existing code. There may be a better way depending on what the functionallity is of this method. Please explain what the purpose is of this `checkAndCreateLogTable` method.

Comment: there are 7-8 method which I need in 80% of my modal. and `checkAndCreateLogTable()` is just a reference where I pass the table name and it check a table a user specific table is present or not if not then create a table from a sample table.